# How do I dynamically change Content Editor web part title via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, title

I have a content editor web part that I want to dynamically change the title on mouse click. I tried using the .text() function, but it's not working :(

Here's the sample of the page:

[image: sample]

The text I want to change is "Deliverables" when I click on the Gate 1 box.

I added this bit of code to the onlick function of the graphic:

[image: code sample]

It's not the whole code, but that's the part that's supposed to change the web part's title.

While the alert function works, neither of the .text("Resources") work. I tried two approaches and commented one out to test which would work, but none did. I looked at the page's source code, and this is the content editor web part:

[image: view source]

What can I do to change the title dynamically? I'm able to extract the text's value, but I'm unable to change it :( Please help :(

Thanks,

Poch

Comment: Thanks! I've added accepts in my previous questions :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<span>Deliverables</span>
```

as

```
<span id="titleSpan">Deliverables</span>
```

and do,

```
$("#titleSpan").text("Resources");
```

**OR**

you can do,

```
$("#WebPartCaptionWPQ6").prev().text("Resources");
```

Comment: I can't do that, unfortunately :( SharePoint is the one responsible in creating the codes for the web parts :( It puts IDs in the TD but not in the span :( I was even hoping that it would put an id in the H3 tag, but it didn't :(

Comment: Ok, here's something weird. I didn't remove the alert function and it seems that the title has indeed changed to "Resources" (it's what shows up in the alert($("#WebPartTitleWPQ6").text());) but the text shown in the web page is still "Deliverables" :(